# Mail PHP not reaching half of people

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I've got a website where people can register and need to validate in ordre to use their account. Unfortunately, some people are not receiving the confirmation mail..

here's the code I'm using

```
function mail_send($arr) {
    if (!isset($arr['to_email'], $arr['from_email'], $arr['subject'], $arr['message'])) {
    throw new HelperException('mail(); not all parameters provided.');
}

$to            = empty($arr['to_name']) ? $arr['to_email'] : '"' . mb_encode_mimeheader($arr['to_name']) . '" <' . $arr['to_email'] . '>';
$from        = empty($arr['from_name']) ? $arr['from_email'] : '"' . mb_encode_mimeheader($arr['from_name']) . '" <' . $arr['from_email'] . '>';

$headers    = array
(
    'MIME-Version: 1.0',
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit',
    'Date: ' . date('r', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']),
    'Message-ID: <' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . '@' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '>',
    'From: ' . $from,
    'Reply-To: ' . $from,
    'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    'X-Mailer: PHP v' . phpversion(),
    'X-Originating-IP: ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'],
);

    mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($arr['subject']) . '?=', $arr['message'], implode("\n", $headers));
}

$arr = array();
$arr['to_email'] = $mail;
$arr['from_email'] = "no-reply@website.com";
$arr['subject'] = "Welcome [Validation]";
$arr['message'] = 'Thank you for registering, you're now able to fully use this website.'."<br><br>".'Username: <b>'.$username.'</b> Password :<b>'.$password.'</b>.'."<br><br>".' You need to validate in order to login...'."<br>".'<a href="a">Validate!</a>'."<br><br>".'Have fun!'."<br><br>".'--- The team.'; 

mail_send($arr);
```

Also, I've got forum cms (phpbb and mybb) running great on the same server with 0 problem related to email..

So what's wrong with my code...

Thank you!

Comment: It is possible there are numerous variables outside your control that effect whether someone receives your email.

Comment: Short answer: rolling your own code is a recipe for invalid message structure and formatting. Use a library.

Comment: I'm using phpmailer now, but I receive a lot of error.. I bet it's because they didn't put the right email..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to look into a mailer class for php like this one https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

saves you a lot of headaches

Comment: yeah I might look into this.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can see nothing wrong with your code, if there were I think even the half will not be getting any mail. I advise you contact your Hosting provider Customer Service for this one.

Comment: But how can my forums installation have a 100% reaching rate..

Comment: Buddy there might be a limit set upon you by the Hosting provider, please recheck. If they told you it is unlimited, then there is definitely a limit and that too a small one.

Comment: Your code possibly missing important headers or sending headers that are blocked by some mailservers, also your from address is very spam sensitive.

Comment: I see, what's a good "from email" then? Also, I'll contact my host to check if there's any limit..

Comment: I am not getting paid for this but I will advise using a Mass mail service like Mailchimp http://mailchimp.com/ for sending mass emails.

Comment: Use the domain of where this script is running from and make sure mail has been setup on the dns for that domain. and no-reply isn't a very good choice, better use a real existing email address where people actually can reply to.